# How can I get the latest date in my query without duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I get the latest date in my query without duplicates and by the latest date only?

```
 SELECT 
  MEMB.LAST_M,
  MEMB.MEMB_N,
  PrintDate
FROM
  MEMB 
  INNER JOIN tblPrint 
    ON MEMB.MEMB_N = tblPrint.MEMB_N 
 WHERE tblPrint.`PrintDate` IN (SELECT tblPrint.`PrintDate` FROM tblPrint)
```

My above query gives me this:

[image: img]

As you can see in the image it includes two "Andres, Jose" one with 2020 date and the other one with 2024 date and one "Loria Marisa" but I just need **1** Andres Jose with 2024 date.

It includes the same value but I don't need it.

Comment: have you try using select distinct and order by desc

Comment: This is a FAQ, so no need to go further but, for next time, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) And welcome to SO

Comment: @Kelvin I tried it but didn't work, the answer by darkRob work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `group by` and `max`. `Group by` for your columns and `max` for your date, since you want to select `max` date only.

```
SELECT 
  MEMB.LAST_M,
  MEMB.MEMB_N,
  MAX(PrintDate)
FROM
  MEMB 
  INNER JOIN tblPrint 
    ON MEMB.MEMB_N = tblPrint.MEMB_N 
 WHERE tblPrint.`PrintDate` IN (SELECT tblPrint.`PrintDate` FROM tblPrint)
 GROUP BY MEMB.LAST_M,
  MEMB.MEMB_N
```

Comment: The where clause is useless, and should be removed